# Setting CLASSPATH during runtime

Tags: java, .net, ikvm

How do I set a CLASSPATH variable during runtime while using IKVM?

I've been trying to do it by using: 
`java.lang.System.setProperty("java.class.path", "whatever");`

The class I'm calling requires a configuration file in the classpath to work - and I keep getting errors that seem to indicate that it hasn't gotten its settings.

Is the way I'm trying to add variable incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing. I had some jar files compiled to a .Net dll but some of those (3rd party) jar files were trying to load their configuration files from the java classpath.

I solved the problem by specifying the -classloader option for the ikvmc tool. Example:

```
ikvmc -out:mydotnetapp.dll -classloader:ikvm.runtime.ClassPathAssemblyClassLoader c:/myjavaapp/lib/*.jar
```

This worked for me!

Source for the solution: http://old.nabble.com/Not-able-to-load-files-from-ClassPath-td31141788.html

Answer (score 3):

If you really can't set the classpath beforehand yourself using the `java`'s `-cp` or `-classpath` argument (why not by the way? that's the normal approach), then you can try to use [`URLClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) instead. Here's a kickoff example:

```
URL url = new URL(whateverPath);
ClassLoader contextCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ClassLoader urlCL = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { url }, contextCL);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlCL);
// ...
```

You only need to be lucky if the class you're calling is *actually* loading its resources through `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()` and thus ***not*** through 
`SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource()`.

Comment: The reason I can't set the classpath beforehand is that I'm running the java code in .Net (jar-files recompiled to .net assemblies) with the IKVM VirtualMachine. IKVM does not read from the classpath.

The example above would work great for any Java-code though :)