# Where does IKVM get its CLASSPATH from?

Tags: java, .net, classpath, embedded-resource, ikvm

I have a .NET assembly that was converted from a jar file. This library looks for files in its classpath. I keep getting missing resource exceptions when running the application.

I have tried:
- Putting the resource file in my bin folder
- Putting the resource file in my source folder, including it in the VS project and setting copy local to on
- setting a CLASSPATH environment variable to a folder containing the resource file

None of the above have worked. Does anyone know where IKVM expects to see its classpath or another way I can get my program to see the resource file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ikvm documentation](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvm.html), `ikvm` behaves similar to java. This should work:

```
ikvm -cp .;relative/path/to/jar/lib.jar com.example.MyClass
```

---

Got it - loading resources from the classpath does work in Java but not in the compiled .net assembly. The `-resource` parameter could be the one that does the trick but unfortunately there's no example on the [ByteCode Compiler page](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.htm).

**Related question**

- [Setting CLASSPATH during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899804/setting-classpath-during-runtime-ikvm)

Comment: The problem with that is that I am using ikvmc so I am not running my JAR file directly, but rather converting it to a .Net library for use in my .Net applications. It looks like the ikvm command expects you to run a jar file.

Comment: Using the code on the related question I was able to load the resource file directory. Thanks for the help.