# how to set classpath at runtime from java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting CLASSPATH during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899804/setting-classpath-during-runtime)

POSSIBLE DUPLICATE: [Setting CLASSPATH during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899804/setting-classpath-during-runtime)

To get the classpath I am using :

```
 ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
     URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
     for(URL url: urls){
         System.out.println("classpath:"+url.getFile());
         }
```

Can some one help me with the code to load the jars in classpath at runtime.

```
ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader
     = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader
     = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("D:\\ms.jar").toURL()},
                          currentThreadClassLoader);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
```

This doesent seem to work.

Comment: Set the CLASSPATH appropriately before the app starts and make the JARs part of it.  I don't see a reason why this can't be sufficient.  Runtime loading of JARs is for app servers, not you and me.

Comment: If I develop an application which load plugins one the fly, the suggested mechanism will be used and the classpath may be important

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899804/setting-classpath-during-runtime possible duplicate?

Comment: _"This doesent seem to work."_. Exception?

Comment: No exception but when I try to print the current classpath I cant see the added jar

Comment: @PrototypeStark the suggested duplicate question is not exactly a duplicate. But the answer to the question you pointed out is an answer to this question if I understand it well.

Comment: @Alban although it isn't a 1:1 copy, its definitely the answer he should have found while he "googled".

Comment: `File("...").toURL()` has been deprecated since Java 1.2!  Are you compiling using a 1.1 SDK or simply ignoring warnings?

Comment: as of now ignoring.... I need this working :(

Answer (score 1):

A complete (coded) solution would be a bit beyond a single Stack Overflow answer, so I'll outline the points you need to be aware of instead if you decide to write your own ClassLoader:

1. The classloader represents (part of) a namespace, and two otherwise identical classes loaded by different classloaders are not "equal". Which means there are a few dangers lurking in classloading, notably singletons suddenly not being so single anymore as well as casts failing unexpectedly.
2. Classloaders (should) work on a pattern of delegating to the "parent" loader before attempting anything themselves (see above).
3. Class loading and linking are two distinct steps (even though example implementations of a classloader such as may be found in blog posts/online Java articles, will combine the two into one for simplicity) Therefore you should not assume that if a parent loader has loaded a class it has also loaded all dependencies ...
4. All this means there is a problem if class A loaded by loader A references a class B which neither loader A nor any of its parents can load: class A may load just fine in loader A but at the point of use it fails because loader A cannot fully resolve (link) it.
5. And you should make sure that your classloader loads classes in a synchronized manner otherwise the issues hinted at in step #1 can leap from duplicates due to classloaders to duplicates from multiple threads using the same classloader as well...

Note: it is **far** easier to just use the `-cp` switch in some wrapper script/batch file for your program.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`ClassLoader#getSystemClassLoader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29) doc:

> This method is first invoked early in the runtime's startup sequence,
>   at which point it creates the system class loader and sets it as the
>   context class loader of the invoking Thread.

When you do `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader)`, you're changing the reference in the current thread, not the one in `ClassLoader`  (and you can't change this one), so from then on you should rely on the new class loader of the current thread to load your classes with something like:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(...)
```